# PHP unlink keeps failing

Tags: php, mysql, unlink

I'm trying to write a script to upload a script to remove an image from my server. I keep getting the error message. Can anyone find anything wrong with this code?

```
// Delete image
if(isset($_GET['deleteImg']) && !empty($_GET['deleteImg']) && $_GET['deleteImg'] == true)
{
 // Get imagepath from database
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT image FROM frankkluytmans WHERE id=$id");
 $imageDeletePath = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

 // Delete image from server
 if(unlink($imageDeletePath['image']))
 {
    // Continue if image has been reset in database
    if(mysql_query("UPDATE frankkluytmans SET `image`='' WHERE id=$id")){
        // once deleted, redirect back to the view page
        header("Location: index.php"); 
    }
 }
 else
 {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.alert('This image could not be deleted.';
    </script>
    <?
 }
}
```

Comment: is the path `absolute` in db field? you might call `unlink` from a different position so it doesn't work because it cannot find the file

Comment: The path in the db field is like this: /gfx/image.png

Comment: and you are in what directory right now?

Comment: print path juste before deleting and you should know what's wrong...

Comment: `getcwd` use this function to print actual folder -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your error is in the `path` of your `unlink()` function, as you said actual field is like `/gfx/image.png` wich doesn't look to me like an absolute path, correct me if i'm wrong.

To delete the `file` and use `unlink()` directly your script should be in the same folder as the image. So i think it would be better to set an `absolute path` to your entry like

```
$path_abs = ' /customers/d/8/e/frankkluytmans.nl/httpd.www/testsite/cms'; //is the `gfx` folder inside `cms` folder? if it is this will work otherwise you have to change
if(unlink($path_abs . $imageDeletePath['image']))
```

Comment: why wouldn't `/gfx/image.png` be an absolute path?

Comment: It could be also, you are right, but i didn't feel so from user while i asked him

Comment: i updated it to "ht tp://www.mysite.nl/testsite/cms".$imageDeletePath['image']but it still doesn't work?

Comment: this is still not the absolute path, this is http address, please check your path with `echo getcwd (); die;` tell me what it output

Comment: this is what I get: /customers/d/8/e/frankkluytmans.nl/httpd.www/testsite/cms